# test cases are failing in setupFilesAfterEnv mode while it is working fine in setupFiles mode in react with jest + enzyme

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on testing react components using jest and enzyme , earlier it was working properly but now when I am testing it is failing all test case when using this

```
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./utils/jestUtils/setupTests.js"
    ],
```

and showing error like

```
● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: base intrinsic for Date.prototype.getUTCFullYear exists, but the property is not available.

  1 | const Enzyme = require('enzyme');
> 2 | const EnzymeAdapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-16');
    |                       ^
  3 | 
  4 | Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });
  5 | 

  at GetIntrinsic (node_modules/es-abstract/GetIntrinsic.js:209:12)
  at callBoundIntrinsic (node_modules/es-abstract/helpers/callBound.js:10:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/es-abstract/2015/YearFromTime.js:9:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/es-abstract/2015/DayWithinYear.js:5:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/es-abstract/2015/DateFromTime.js:7:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/es-abstract/es2015.js:22:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/es-abstract/es6.js:3:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/array.prototype.find/index.js:4:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/airbnb-prop-types/src/childrenOfType.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/airbnb-prop-types/src/index.js:8:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/airbnb-prop-types/index.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/createMountWrapper.jsx:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/index.js:2:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:41:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/index.js:4:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (utils/jestUtils/setupTests.js:2:23)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)


Test Suites: 98 failed, 98 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        44.888s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ***@1.0.0 test: `jest --verbose --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

but when I am changing it to

```
 "setupFiles": [
      "./utils/jestUtils/setupTests.js"
    ],
```

it is working fine and all the the test case are passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by deleting `node_modules` & `package-lock.json` file & reinstalling it by `npm install`